# C datatypes in Java

Tags: java, c, type-conversion

I have an application in C and need to re-write it to Java. I have a problem with data types. I am not sure which data type is equal to the C ones in Java.

There are those I need to find out equal datatypes in java programming language for.

- `unsigned char`
- `unsigned short`
- `short int`
- `unsigned long`

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned numerical types.

Comment: The only unsigned type in Java is `char`. Its size is equal to `uint16_t` in C, which is often the same as `unsigned short`.

Comment: Also note those types are not standard size in C, ie. number of bits in them is implementation specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pick something based on the ranges you need

- **byte**: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.
- **int**: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31 - 1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^32 - 1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.
- **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).
- **long**: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63 - 1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^64 - 1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned long.
- **short**: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You left out `byte` -- signed 8-bit.

Comment: `>>>` to get C's unsigned `>>` could also be mentioned here. (And the formatting of the powers is screwed up...)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have unsigned types (apart from `char`, which pretends not to be a number)

- `byte` is one byte, in range `-128` to `127`
- `char` is two bytes (unsigned), but only generally used for characters, not numbers
- `short` is also two bytes, in range `-32768` to `32767`
- `int` is four bytes
- `long` is eight bytes

Edit -- char is unsigned (thanks to Hot Licks in comments)